# What is :: in declaration and why is it used?

Tags: c++, fstream

I came from C working environment and new to C++.
Please help in the following declaration.

Inside some function foo() I have found this code .

`::ifstream ifObj;`

I know it is declaring input filestream object.

But I completely don't know this concept of `::` scope resolution here.
What is this and why is it used in declaration of object.

Could not have found out anywhere, hence asked.

Comment: `::` without a namespace means "global namespace"; I have no idea why would someone use it for `ifstream`, though.

Comment: First link from google: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr175.htm
Keywords: "c++ scope resolution operator"

Comment: @MaximKumpan : Thanks for link , will see it

Comment: Why the question is downvoted, must comment

Comment: Old implementations of ifstream were often in the global namespace - perhaps this code relied on the old one as opposed to the standard one.

Comment: @Omkant, I downvoted the question and commented, because a simple Google search yielded the answer in 4 seconds.

Comment: nope I tried but, I was not satisfied with that , then asked here.

Comment: @MaximKumpan : Please see the aspect of this question not only, looking the question and searching on the google. I too have searched over internet then only asked. It is request to just donwvoting the question doesn't mean the existense of it is finished. I am expecting someone to understand the question and answer it..BTW I am also trying to find it anyway

Comment: @Omkant: If you want an answer specific to how it's used in *your code*, then you need to show *your code*.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Sorry Ben, It's the restriction, I can't post the code here. But Nowhere in the file it's repeated. At only one it's been used

Comment: @Omkant: Then you won't be getting any more specific answers here than you will from google, because we don't have the needed information.  It's not going to get any more informative than sfjac's comment above.

Comment: @BenVoigt :  I am also considering that too, and looking into C++ standard.

Comment: Don't overconcern yourself with the reason of the operator where it is. It could have been placed there just as easily at the whim of a previous developer. It does one thing and one thing only, and if there are no local scope declarations of ifstream to circumvent, it's pointless. End of story. Try removing it and see if it compiles if it worries you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for your Question,

It is to let the compiler to resolve the disambiguity while tracing the origin of the type ifstream.

ifstream may be declared in 3rd party libs like boost to provide different meaning,

Consider you have,

```
namespace boost {
 typedef int ifstream;
}

using namespace boost;

//but here you want global ifsteam, not from boost, so
::ifstream ifObj; // Here you are creating a object for global ifstream, not for boost's ifstream,
```

Comment: `::` is used to access global variable inside local scope to avoid collision with local variable having same name........But point is why anyone will declare like this

Comment: @Omkant The symbol may providing different meaning in different namespaces. But for the sake of clarity they can have same names, but whenever collision is encountered use explicit namespaces to distinguish.

Comment: Please don't stress on accessing the variable, my quesiton is regarding why it is used in declaration.

Comment: @Omkant ::ifstream ifObj; means you are using global ifstream type. Regardless of declaration or using, both has same meaning.

Comment: Thanks, I think it could be one of the reason for using it. Still thinking of no one does such kind of `typedef` not even in my code.. But satisfied by your answer because it's been added to avoid future collisions. +1

Answer (score 1):

The unary scope resolution operator is used to refer to the global namespace version of a token if that token is overridden in a local namespace.

F.ex:

```
int count = 0;

int main(void) {
  int count = 0;
  ::count = 1;  // set global count to 1
  count = 2;    // set local count to 2
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `::` is used to access global variable inside local scope to avoid collision with local variable having same name........But point is why anyone will declare like this

Comment: @Omkant, programmers are people. And people can be all sorts of qualities. Ask the guy who wrote this. :P

Comment: @Omkant, on a more serious note, check the local scope in case ifstream has been overridden at some point for some reason. Not likely, but plausible.